# Google Play Store "Doesn't support required screen densities & sizes" despite allowing all

Tags: android, android-manifest, compatibility, google-play-console

In the Google Play Console device catalog, there are numerous newer devices such as the Galaxy S9+ that are listed as unsupported with the following explanation:

```
Doesn't support required screen densities & sizes <compatible-screens>
- 640, SMALL
- 640, NORMAL
- 640, LARGE
- 640, XLARGE
```

However, I thought I fixed this issue by adding the following to my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:resizeable="true" />
```

It looks like I am explicitly allowing all screen densities and sizes, yet some devices still say they are incompatible.

For what it's worth, I do not use the `<compatible-screens>` element anywhere in my manifest (as this essentially acts as a white list and Google recommend you not to use it normally).

I'm not sure what the repeated 640 means, but I had the same message on some other devices and they are now compatible with the above change to my manifest. Anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: Could potentially be [this requirement](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution#MaxAspectRatio)?

Comment: Just remove the `<supports-screen>` block entirely if you want to support all of them.

Comment: @ianhanniballake by adding the `<supports-screens>` block I support 9 more devices than previously. I initially did not have the block at all and still had the same issue, but with more devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible your APK inherits a compatible-screens section from a third-party library you are including in the app, without you knowing it?

To check this, you could try the following command:

`~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/$version/aapt dump xmltree your.apk AndroidManifest.xml`

This prints out the manifest generated for your app. Look for any suspicious "screens" lines.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me solve the issue. Apparently I had `compatibleScreens` set in my gradle file.

Comment: I had `<compatible-screens>` as mentioned here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element